# How to create checkboxes with preselected values from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox, default-value

I am trying to create checkbox with preselected values which comes from my database (Genres). For example, if this movie has 3 different genres: comedy, romance and action (in the database), these genres will be preselected (have default value) checkboxes. The problem is that i need all the checkboxes (genres) which I get from the following SQL-query:
`$sql = 'SELECT Movie.* FROM Movie WHERE Movie.id = ?';`

and default values (ticked checkboxes) which I get from the following SQL-query:
`$sql = 'SELECT Genre.name FROM (Genre JOIN Movie2Genre ON Movie2Genre.idGenre = Genre.id) JOIN Movie ON Movie2Genre.idMovie = Movie.id WHERE Movie.id = ?';`

If you have a solution or any simpler method I would love to hear you out. If you find anything here unclear, please tell me and I will do my best correct/add necessary information.

(PS: My if-statement is not working as I want it to do)

```
        <?php
        foreach ($allGenre as $val){
            foreach ($aktivGenre as $act) {
                if ($act==$val) {
                    $active = "checked";
                }else {
                    $active = "";
                }
            }


            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$val["name"]}' value='{$val["name"]}'".$active." >{$val["name"]}"; //$active="selected" when 
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any html? What exactly are default values? What should the user do with those checkboxes? Is he sending it to a favorite list? Will php process on postback?

Comment: @FabianoAraujo Yes. It's all inside a HTML form tag (<form></form). Basically what it is supposed to do is to recieve all the genres that the movie has. So when you get on the edit-page its genres will be checked already. So if you want to change anything you will just have to uncheck an old genre or check a new genre. And I will be using PHP to send the information to MYSQL.

Comment: I would make a query to get all genres available, fit the resultset in a array where the index is actually the ID  of the genre, next make another query, this one looking for the user's options. Now looping through the all the options to print it as a checkbox, check if it also exists in the users' genres array with array_key_exists. If it's true, then add the "checked" property.

Comment: I will try the array_key_exists and see if I can manage to make it work :)

Comment: Great. If any trouble I'll be able to put some example in an hour or so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will let you know if I succeed or not.

Comment: array_key_exists requires a string and an array. Since I have two arrays one for the active genres (my second sql-query above) and the other for all the genres (my first sql-query above), I am not sure how to compare the two.